# How do 'operator' functions work when they're defined in terms of a class rather than an actual operator?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I was exploring an online course on design patterns in C++, and I came across a strange "cast" (?) using an `operator` function declaration.

The minimal set up is as follows (actual code below):

```
class A {
    ...

    static B build();
};

class B {
    A a;
};


int main()
{
    A obj = A::build();
}
```

Since the `build` function returns an object of type `B`, there is a type mismatch and the code fails to compile. To correct this, the instructor defined the following function in class B:

```
operator A() { return a; }
```

My question is, how does this work? I understand the mechanism for overloading operators, but in this case we're overloading an actual class, rather than an operator. What is being done when we declare an operator function using another class? What's more, there's no return type defined, does the compiler just assume the return type is the same as the class in which the function is defined? (i.e... `B operator A() { ... }`) I can't really wrap my head around this concept, intuitively.

I had never heard of this method at all, let alone considered it being possible at all before coming across it just now. I've been trying to research this online, but -understandably, I would say- all my search results return links for basic overloading, or at least more traditional overloading, using operators.

---

For context, this lecture is on the "Builder" design pattern, using an Html element and an Html builder structure. This is my base code, without modifications yet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct HtmlBuilder;

struct HtmlElement {
    std::string name;
    std::string text;

    std::vector<HtmlElement> elements;

    const std::size_t indent_size = 2;

    std::string str(const int indent = 0) const {
        std::ostringstream oss;

        std::string indentation(indent_size * indent, ' ');

        oss << indentation << "<" << name << ">\n";

        if (!text.empty())
            oss << std::string(indent_size * (indent + 1), ' ') << text << '\n';

        for (const auto& element : elements)
            oss << element.str(indent + 1);

        oss << indentation << "</" << name << ">\n";

        return oss.str();
    }

    static HtmlBuilder build(const std::string& rootName);
};

struct HtmlBuilder {
    HtmlElement root;

    void addChild(const std::string& childName, const std::string& childText) {
        HtmlElement childElement { childName, childText };
        root.elements.emplace_back(childElement);
    }

    std::string str() const { return root.str(); }
};

HtmlBuilder HtmlElement::build(const std::string& rootName) {
    return { rootName };
}

int main()
{
    HtmlBuilder builder { "ul" };
    builder.addChild("li", "hello");
    builder.addChild("li", "world");

    std::cout << builder.str();
}
```

Output, as expected:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    hello
  </li>
  <li>
    world
  </li>
</ul>
```

When demonstrating the "fluent builder" pattern, the instructor had us modify our `addChild` function to return a reference to the builder structure.

The `HtmlBuilder::addChild` function is modified as follows: the return type is changed from `void` to `HtmlBuilder&` (returning `*this`)

```
HtmlBuilder& addChild(const std::string& childName, const std::string& childText) {
    HtmlElement childElement { childName, childText };
    root.elements.emplace_back(childElement);

    return *this;
}
```

The `main` function is then rewritten:

```
int main()
{
    auto builder = HtmlElement::build("ul").addChild("li", "hello").addChild("li", "world");

    std::cout << builder.str();
}
```

The output is again:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    hello
  </li>
  <li>
    world
  </li>
</ul>
```

Having successfully defined and implemented the fluent builder pattern, the instructor now posed the following question:

> How could we get an Html element object from our `build` function?

My immediate reaction was to think about maybe providing a getter method to the `HtmlBuilder` class. Something trivial, like this:

```
struct HtmlBuilder {
    ...
    HtmlElement getElement() const { return root; }
};
```

You would then "build and get" the element like so:

```
int main()
{
    const auto builder = HtmlElement::build("ul").addChild("li", "hello").addChild("li", "world");
    const auto element = builder.getElement();

    std::cout << builder.str() << '\n';
    std::cout << element.str() << '\n';
}
```

Both outputs would then be the same. The instructor, however, chose a much different and much more interesting method. Rather than doing it in two steps, via my "build and get" approach, he did the following.

He first rewrote the `main` function like so (note that he is both building and getting the element in one step, unlike me):

```
int main()
{
    HtmlElement element = HtmlElement::build("ul").addChild("li", "hello").addChild("li", "world");

    std::cout << element.str();
}
```

Initially the compiler rejects this modification because the result of the `HtmlElement::build` call is an `HtmlBuilder` object. So to solve this problem, the second thing the instructor did was to define the following function in the `HtmlBuilder` class:

```
operator HtmlElement() const { return root; }
```

Having done this, the code compiles without a hitch and the application output is once again:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    hello
  </li>
  <li>
    world
  </li>
</ul>
```

Again, my question is, why or how does this work? What is being done when we declare an `operator` function using another class? I understand the machinations of the usual operator overloading. It makes intuitive sense to me to overload `()`, `[]`, or `=`, but I don't understand how or why this case works. There's not even a declared return type; does the compiler just assume it's meant to return the current class type?

Thank you for your time, everyone.

Comment: It's all in here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator Despite the question being extremely well written, it's too broad methinks.

Comment: @Bathsheba I agree with you, actually. This is exactly what I needed, just the name of this mechanism; I was having a hard time coming up with it on my own, so I did my best to ask a broad question specifically. Thank you for the source, much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re: "we're overloading an actual class". No. `operator A() { return a; }` is overloading an operator; note the keyword `operator`. This defines a **conversion operator** that will be used when the code calls for a conversion from an object of type `B` to an object of type `A`.

The use in your example is a bit obscure. Here's an easier example:

```
B b;
A obj = b;
```

Creating the `obj` object requires converting the `b` object to an object of type `A`, and that's the job that `operator A()` does.

In your example, the call to `A::build` returns an object of type `B`, so in the code

```
A obj = A::build();
```

the call to `A::build()` returns a temporary object of type `B`, and the conversion operator (`operator A()`) converts that object to an object of type `A`, which is used to initialize `obj`.

Answer (score 2):

That's a [user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). The return type is the type after `operator`, i.e. the destination type. This adds an extra implicit conversion for the type, which is used whenever implicit conversion is considered.

Using the word `operator` isn't indeed exactly the clearest keyword to use because it doesn't *really* define an operator (although it can interact with cast operations), but I guess it was to avoid adding another reserved word.